# /sbin/service lazyness shortcut

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos

I'm running CentOS 5 and disabled the root login for security reasons.
Now, as root I could start and stop services like this:

```
httpd restart
mysqld stop
postfix start
```

but with the new user I set up I have to use `/sbin/service process command`

How can I set it up that the user also can access the process quickly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add /etc/init.d/ to the path - e.g.

```
PATH=$PATH:/etc/init.d
```

And put it into the user's .profile

Comment: okay I put this into .bash_profile, do I have to restart anything?

Comment: you need to log in again. Alternatively you can do a `. ~/.bash_profile` from an active shell for the change to take effect

Comment: logged out and logged back in, worked! But I cannot access the commands once I sudo su any hints?

Comment: Yes, use `sudo su -` or even better `sudo -i`.

Comment: `sudo su - <username>` - the `-` is important as it acts like a login shell and thus sources the profile files (just like when you login)

Comment: got it! I just had to do the same thing again for the "su user"